# Phidgets with ROS error

Tags: ros, phidgets

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,
I am a newbie in ROS. So please excuse me if my query sounds naive.

I am trying to use a phidget spatial sensor input in a ros node. For this I am trying to catkin_make the phidgets_driver package in ros hydro. However I get the following error:

```
CMake Error at ~/catkin_ws/devel/share/phidgets_api/cmake/phidgets_apiConfig.cmake:165 (find_package):
  Could not find module Findlibphidgets.cmake or a configuration file for
  package libphidgets.

  Adjust CMAKE_MODULE_PATH to find Findlibphidgets.cmake or set
  libphidgets_DIR to the directory containing a CMake configuration file for
  libphidgets.  The file will have one of the following names:

    libphidgetsConfig.cmake
    libphidgets-config.cmake

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/hydro/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:75 (find_package)
  phidgets_drivers/phidgets_ir/CMakeLists.txt:4 (find_package)
```

I have no clue what is wrong here. Btw, I tried the example at [Phidgets linux support](http://www.phidgets.com/docs/OS_-_Linux) and it works without any problem.

Any help with phidgets with ROS will be highly appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/221854/phidgets-with-ros-error/) by [SaugataBiswas](https://answers.ros.org/users/25229/saugatabiswas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-12-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

CMake cannot find libphidgest.  The most common reason is that you have not installed the libphidgets package on your system or in your workspace. http://wiki.ros.org/libphidgets

Please provide more details about how you setup your system, and we might be able to help you resolve your dependencies.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2015-12-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0